# FBSDKMessageDialog sharing link take very long time to load when in Messenger

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I tried to let users able to share my URL via Messenger with Facebook iOS SDK 4.6 . The problem is when the Messenger opened. The "send field" is empty and take sometimes to for the sharing link to appear.  This is annoying . Are there anyway to solve this ?

Here is my code

```
 FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];


    if([messageDialog canShow]) {

        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        content.contentURL = shareURL;
        content.contentTitle = shareTitle;
        content.imageURL = imageURL;

        content.contentDescription = @"#xxxxx";

        messageDialog.shareContent = content;
        messageDialog.delegate = self;

        [messageDialog show];

    }
```

Comment: Did you ever work out this problem?

Comment: It is up to the speed of our website. No other solution. If the previewing takes longer than 8-10 sec, the messenger prompt back to the app

Comment: Ok this is a different issue for me. The contentTitle never gets set.